# Short ASP.NET Date Program

Tags: javascript, asp.net, server-side

I keep getting a runtime error but my schools servers doesn't like to print out errors. I copied this straight from the book and I've checked it quite a few times - it looks right to me. Am I missing something here? It just tells me `runtime error`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>A Simple ASP.NET Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td{background-color:black;color:yellow;}
        strong{font-family:arial, sans-serif;}
        p{font-size:14pt}
    </style>
    <script runat="server" langauge="JScript">
        var dayAndTime : DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>A Simple ASP.NET Example</strong>
    <p>
        <table border="6">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% Response.Write(dayAndTime.ToShortTimeString()); %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% Response.Write(dayAndTime.ToShortDateString()); %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you run it?

Comment: It just tells me `runtime error`

Comment: 'var dayAndTime : DateTime = DateTime.Now;'  it should not be a correct js statement... Check below code server side include..

Comment: you can download free editions of VS.NET and run it on your own computer, where you will have complete access to error messages, logs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot determine exactly what is causing the error and you only have 3 lines of .net, try taking them out one at a time until the program runs.  This will tell you what line is at least causing the problem.  Start with the `response.write` :p

Comment: Yeah I guess those aren't causing the problem. I'm still getting the runtime error :S

Comment: fixed it: I needed <%@ Page Language="JScript" %>

Comment: ahhh hah yeah that'll do it.  In general by the way I find reducing the code to be a useful way of isolating runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You spelled language wrong. Since it is in the html tag, it didn't correct you and just thought it was VB or C#.

```
 <script runat="server" language="JScript">
         var dayAndTime : DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <strong>A Simple ASP.NET Example</strong>
    <p>
        <table border="6">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% Response.Write(dayAndTime.ToShortTimeString()); %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <% Response.Write(dayAndTime.ToShortDateString());%>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```